# How to transform text with characters to HTML Entities with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, html-entities

I Want to use an URL to call a method but i need it to be written with HTML Entities:

so if i have `http://www.myurl.com/foobar` for example using a Ruby on Rails helper i can get something like:

`http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Ffoobar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything built directly into rails to do all of that escaping, but if you `require 'cgi'` you can use `CGI::escape`.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :001 > require 'cgi'
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :002 > s = "http://www.myurl.com/foobar"
 => "http://www.myurl.com/foobar" 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :003 > CGI::escape(s)
 => "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Ffoobar"
```

Obviously, to make it look a little nicer in your views, or wherever, you could wrap that method in a helper.

Answer (score 1):

there is the great rubygem "htmlentities" which does the trick: http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/

Comment: This is correct as well but I'm on a reseller host so I'd have to wait so much time for the support team to install the gem

Comment: why don't you copy it to your /lib or vendor folder?

Comment: Because the reseller server takes too long to reload configuration.... it's running on fcgi